Benefits of using Optimizely SDK vs API
We are in the process of implementing Optimizely for feature toggles.
Should we use the C# SDK or the API?
What are the pros/cons for each?
I couldn't find any information about comparing them on the Optimizely website.

The SDK just makes it easier, like most client SDKs I think? Personally, I use the C# SDK. Haven't found anything I can't do with the SDK (yet).
